# How to encode an Java Object(Class) and decode it again?

Tags: java, server, base64, multiple-instances

I want to make a bridge between two Java Engines and me don't want to use any data storages like MySql or Files. So I think the best option is to create a SocketServer and send the given Information. But my problem is that I don't know how to transfer an by the variable type itself. I want to send it directly from Field to Field so I have the exactly object on the other side. But I don't what to send a special Object or Class I want Something which is able to transfer every class.

Comment: sounds almost exactly like [serialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html), or maybe [REpresentational State Transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data transfer object should implement `Serializable` interface to have any of its state serialized and deserialized. An example:

```
public class MyDTO implements Serializable {

  private String field1;
  private int field2;

  // getters and setters
}
```

You can then write and read the object on the sockets. Example:

```
// writing

socket.getOutputStream.write(myDtoObject);

// reading
MyDTO dto = (MyDTO) socket.getInputStream.readObject();
```

I highly recommend reading through the Javadoc for more info about the `Serializable` interface: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html